# How about a RELATIONSHIPS tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have to laugh that there is a "monsters" tag with 3 questions, but no [relationships](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) tag.

While there is a "romance" tag, I don't think it's quite the same thing.

A search for "relationships" offers over 1000 entries – a quick surface look suggests the majority do not use the "romance" tag.

Should we add a "relationships" tag?

Comment: Could you give some examples of questions you'd use it for?  Questions where [tag:romance] is not appropriate and [tag:character-development] is just too big and broad.  I can imagine wanting something for family dynamics.  Or interpersonal relationships between characters, but I'm not convinced yet.

Comment: Yes, I think you are on to it. Relationships is a dynamic *between* or *among* characters, not character development. It also *adjusts* characters as a group dynamic. If you type "relationship" into the search and take a look on the 1st couple pages at which questions DON'T have a romance tag, there are many platonic friendships, families, … actually digging through a few pages, maybe "platonic" should be the tag. It would reduce the number of redundant platonic questions.

Comment: 163 questions with this search: https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=relationship+-%5Bromance%5D+is%3Aq  Some are indeed about portraying an actual non-romantic/non-sexual relationship.  Others just use the word.

Comment: So the question is, what would it add to have the tag?  And yeah, there are enough people asking "how do I portray this relationship" that it seems reasonable.  And what to name it?

Comment: maybe relationship can replace romance as a more general tag for character-character interactions?

Comment: @NofP [tag:romance] needs to stay because it is a genre.  But it might be reasonable to split it so [tag:romance] is only for the genre and [tag:relationships] is for all relationships, including romance between/among characters.  This would not be a horrible retagging project (only 49 questions in [tag:romance] and most are for the genre I think).  But it would still be a project.  I'm wishy washy.

Comment: @Cyn while you suggestion sounds like the right thing to me, I totally second your doubts about the amount of work it would require.

Comment: Agree that **Romance** appears to be used as the genre, and often avoided for questions about *relationships* that don't fit the Romance genre. The genre is perceived as "bad", and a romantic relationship is just one very specific type of relationship.

Comment: Okay, you should create it.  I want to be able to use it when I retag (which is often) but it was your idea so you should get the credit for creating it.  Just add it to one post and that will be enough to start.

Comment: Will do. I could also take responsibility? I guess I may need a little hand holding…

Comment: Just checked and there is a RELATIONSHIPS tag. Has it been added in response to this question? @Cyn

Comment: Yes, I created it

Comment: Sorry wetcircuit I just now saw your request for help with it.  Sometimes SE notifies me if someone replies to my comment without tagging me, but usually not.  But it all looks good.  I noticed the [tag:romance] tag wiki was never updated, so I did that.  You can re-edit if you like.

Comment: For once, I'm in favor of having a new tag O__O

Answer (score 5):

## Yes we should add the tag.

Using [Secespitus' excellent tag creation question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/33442) for this situation.

**1. Ask yourself how many questions you have about this topic: is this probably the only one or is this a topic you want to ask about more regularly?**

Only you can answer this, but given that you are asking about it I would say it is likely. I would also think I could ask a few questions on this in the future.

**2. Look through the existing questions: how many already use the word or similar words and might profit from the tag?**

You've already found [163 questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=relationship+-%5Bromance%5D+is%3Aq) that talk about it. It is a very common topic and many of those would benefit from the tags existence.

**3. Look through the existing tags: is one of them already encompassing what you are trying to convey?**

[romance](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance) is the closest thing we have and we have already identified situations (non-romantic relationships) where it is not appropriate. [character-development](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) is close but only deals with a single character not a relationship.

**4. Look through Meta: have there been similar requests or precedent cases where something similar has been created/denied?**

I can't find anything that relates to this tag.

**5. Think about the sites scope: do you think that a lot of people will profit from these tags when they are asking questions about the specific topic of the site you are on?**

I can see plenty of scope for this to be beneficial to the site.

**6. Think about the tag's scope: is it well-defined and obvious to users coming to the site?**

With a decent tag wiki and usage guidance I can't see how this tag would be confusing. *"This tag is for questions about creating/developing relationships between characters"*. Seems obvious to me.

Combining all these things I think that *yes* we should create this tag. It is useful, well-defined and popular. The only issue will be modifying the [romance](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance) tag to only be about the genre and moving other relationship related questions onto the new tag.

Comment: *"[tag:character-development] is close but only deals with a single character not a relationship."* The tag wiki excerpt for that says "Anything pertaining to developing the details associated with characters in your writing." Nothing there to suggest to me that it is by definition limited to a single character. Character development often happens in interaction with other characters.

Comment: I hate to be sexist, but insisting all relationships can be described through individual character development sounds like a **male bias**. Heroes "level up" and "win a girl" as a notch on their character arc, but it doesn't effect them or generate any influence on the plot – it's just a reflection of their own achievements… Why have "villain" if it's just a kind of character development? Why have any tags other than "story" or "fiction". Saying it doesn't exist or is invalid because it can be reducted to a broader tag isn't really addressing the topic, it's just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: @wetcircuit I didn't say it could and I don't think aCVn was either. I don't really know why you think we were. They said that the tag currently includes character development of all kinds which could be considered to be developing both characters with a relationship. No one has attached gender to this discussion and it doesn't help to do so.

Comment: @aCVn maybe it does cover it. But I'm not sure it should. There is a lot more to developing a relationship that isn't just character development. I might edit my answer tomorrow but I still think the tag should exist.

Comment: @linksassin, I was replying to aCVn's comment specifically, why "character development" doesn't cover it.

Comment: @wetcircuit I don't have a problem with [tag:character-development] covering relationships because I see the tag as being either singular *or* pl.  But I acknowledge that a tag for the development between or among characters is a reasonable addition at this point in our stack's development.

Comment: @Cyn Agree, and I realize (now) that suggesting new tags is actually a burden, not an organizational suggestion. I will refrain from the future. tbh, I'd rather you finish your novel than feel obligated to clean up tags for questions from 2014.

Comment: @wetcircuit LOL!  I actually enjoy cleaning up tags, I just keep it slower than I might to avoid flooding the home page.  I'm in a particularly stressful period right now and find I'm not able to focus on writing, though I try, but for some reason SE is just the right amount of short-term action and focus for me to feel like I'm doing something.